# Nested Cross-Validation with Test Set (Model Selection)

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-comparison

I have seen many examples on Nested CV where someone takes the entire dataset and performs nested CV on it.

My question is: for model comparison shouldn't we first split the original dataset into train and test once, and then perform Nested CV (so with both inner and outer loops) on the train set?

This way, once we have our best models resulting from the different Nested CV rounds for each candidate ML algorithm, we can compare them on the same original test set.

Comment: Usually people do CV when they do not have enough data for splitting it, so that may be the reason.

Comment: Well but what about when doing model comparison?

Comment: Well, again, it would be nice, but if you do not have enough data, you will use the CV results to compare them.

Comment: I never said I don’t have enough data. I’m just asking in an ideal setting. I have plenty of data.

Comment: In that case you should split the data and retain a test set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are applying model selection you will need an additional test set to perform out of sample performance estimation.

This is necessary due to [degrading performance during your second step of inference](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v11/cawley10a.html) (your model selection is inference).

You are allowed to use the test set **only once** to estimate the performance of your final estimator (e.g. ML algorithm).

Exception:
If you are just interested in the best performing model you could theoretically leave this step out (no test set). However, in this case you never estimated the performance of your final classifier.

Comment: Thank you. But what if, after I perform model selection, I want to give a final estimate for the final ML algorithm I selected as the best one? Should I have kept this original test set and not used it all along until this final test, or will it be ok to redo a new train-test split and use this final ML Algo against this new test set?

Comment: Yes, you are not allowed to use it until your final estimate and only once. Only this will be an unbiased estimate.

Comment: You are not allowed to train, validate and select models and later draw a test set from this training data and retrain.

Comment: Every decision  - even if it is subconscious - made based on information from the test set influences the performance of your estimator on the test set. That is why you are not allowed to use it in anyway.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/18347/80280

Comment: Thank you. So effectively when doing model comparisons should the best model the model that on average does best during nested CV (which is only performed on the original training set) or should the best model be the one that performs best on the held out test set (which was held out all along and not used in any way during Nested CV). Thanks!

Comment: hold out set is only used to estimate performance on your "best" classifier determined by CV.

Comment: But what if a classifier among the many compares during nested cv performs better during nested cv and then worse than others on the final test set? Why should that be ignored ?

Comment: if you dont need an unbiased estimate of the performance you can simply use CV and not keep a test set. 

If you need an unbiasd estimate you cannot apply model selection in this step.